# Sunspot: boost elements when match a multiple values field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have an object Foo which has many objects Bee.
    class Foo
       has_many :bees
I index my object A with Sunspot SOLR like this.

```
searchable do
  text :title, boost: 5
  text :content, boost: 2
  integer :bee_ids, multiple: true
  ...
end
```

to keep track of Bee ids related to my Foo object.

Now I have a User that performs searches on Foos objects. The User has many Bees too.

```
class User
    has_many :bees
    ...
end
```

When I search Foos objects I would like to boost objects which have bees that matches User's bees.

```
Foo.search do
    fulltext query
    any_of do
       ...
       with(:bee_ids, @user.bees.pluck(:id))
    end
end
```

I want to give priorities to objects that matches user's interests. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Well. I found a solution for the problem above.
You need to use `bq` parameter to do that and give a boost to that condition.

I added

```
adjust_solr_params do |params|
  params[:bq] = " bee_ids_im:(#{@user.bees.pluck(:id).join(' OR ')})^20"
end
```

and I give a boost to the above condition of 20 times.

Actually that the solution to the more generic problem of giving boost to specific conditions in the query.

Sunspot support boost queries with boost command.
So I changed my query with:

```
Foo.search do
  fulltext query do
    boost(20.0) do
      with(:bee_ids, @user.bees.pluck(:id))
    end
  end
  any_of do
    ...
    with(:bee_ids, @user.bees.pluck(:id))
  end
end
```

and I obtained the same result.

Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: It did help me, thanks for answering your question.

Comment: the boost in the second query only works when a search term is given, and completely ignored otherwise, right? That's what it did when I tested it.

Comment: Also does this only boost documents that have any of theses interests, compared to others that dont have them? Or is a document that has 3 out of 4 interests always appear ahead of one that has 2?